# MS Access ODBC Call Failed on Dlookup

Tags: ms-access, azure-sql-database, linked-tables

I have a linked table to a SQL Azure DB instance.

I'm calling the following: 
DLookup("dptLunchDuration", "tblEmpDeptRef", "dptID=" & department)

At this line, I'm getting the error:

ODBC--call failed.

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Restricted data type attribute violation (#0)

The type of dptLunchDuration is datetime2(0) and all values are currently 2015/11/07 12:00:00 AM

I can't get to the root of the problem, does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you look up another field? DateTime2 cannot be read by the ODBC driver other than as text as it doesn't match the lower resolution of Access' DateTime.

Comment: @Gustav re: *"DateTime2 cannot be read by the ODBC driver other than as text"* - That is not entirely true, at least for ODBC linked tables against a server-based (as opposed to cloud-based) SQL Server instance. A `DATETIME2(0)` column is mapped to a `Date/Time` field, not a `Text` field. (I just tried it again to be sure.)

Comment: You are right. I just made a test. I thought it was for all settings of DateTime(_n_) where _n_ defaults to 7 that the mapping was to text. But setting _n_ to 0 matches Access DateTime. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Can you test similar code against a local instance of SQL Server to see if it's an "Azure thing"? Can you open [tblEmpDeptRef] in Datasheet view from Access (assuming that it's an ODBC linked table) and see the [dptLunchDuration] values there? FWIW your DLookup function works fine for me against my local SQL Server (Express) instance using SQL Server Native Client 10.0.

Comment: @GordThompson: I made two tests using either the _SQL Server_ or the _SQL Server Native Client 11.0_ driver and with fields of DateTime2(_n_) with values of _n_ from 0 to 7. The result is quite simple: The old driver maps DateTime2 as Text while the native driver maps as DateTime. Access version is 2016 and SQL Server 2008 R2. I didn't know - thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help -- since I had created the dbtLunchDuration column for this enhancement, I've changed the type to integer. And the data comes back as I expected.

Comment: @VFein: Are you good to go or still need help?

Comment: I'm good to go. Thank you.